# Stop BufferedReader if the same text is read

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

I have a buffer reader working to read a text file then save the read data as a string.  The buffer reader is in a continuous loop reading the text file every second.  I would like to do a Thread.sleep if the buffer reader reads the same text two times in a row.

For example if the buffer reader reads "foo" then when it is ran again in the next second if it reads "foo" again then the thread sleeps for a certain amount of time.

I have the buffer reader within a try method but I do not know how to get it to do the above.

Could anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep track of the previous line read in in a String variable, which you can initialize as an empty string. When you read in each line, check whether it's `equals()` to the previously stored line in that variable. If so, do what you want to do, like `Thread.sleep()`. Otherwise save the current line into that variable. In code:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));
    String foo = "";
    String old = "";
    while((foo = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(foo.equals(old)) {
            System.out.println("Sleeping...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } else {
            old = foo;
        }
    }
```